# Laravel 5.2 trouble with SQL query in eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am having trouble with eloquent in Laravel 5.2

What I want to achieve is (hopefully) a query which fulfills these steps:

1. updated_at >= value1
2. updated_at <= value2
3. event = value3
4. groupBy = value4
5. count entries of each "group" (each grouped By group)

***Output***: latest updated_at for each group (max(updated_at)) and the count value for each group

What I have so far is:

Table 'logs' overview:

```
---------------------------
| id         | increment    |
-----------------------------
| key        | varchar(255) |
-----------------------------
| video_id   | varchar(255) |
-----------------------------
| event      | varchar(255) |
-----------------------------
| created_at | timestamp    |
-----------------------------
| updated_at | timestamp    |
-----------------------------
```

Query in Laravel:

```
$showed = self::where('updated_at','>=',$value1)->where('updated_at','<=',$value2)->where('event',$value3)->groupBy($avlue4)->get();
```

What I am missing are step 5 and the resulting output. And I have no idea how I could include this to the Laravel eloquent.

Question: Does anyone have a concrete idea of how to achieve this query? If it's not possible, what are the steps to take?

Comment: Please share table definition(s) and desired output. This isn't Laravel specific, you first need a proper SQL query for the table(s) you are querying.

Comment: You need to pass an expression for the aggregate column 'count' which you wish to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone also has troubles with building this kind of eloquent: My solution was to group the query by ID, so the entries in Array would be something like:

```
[0] => [Object, Object],
[1] => [Object]
```

My query:

```
$temp = self::where('updated_at','>=',$month_start)
        ->where('updated_at','<=',$month_end)
        ->where('event','completed')
        ->orWhere('event', 'showed')->get();
    $result = $temp->groupBy('id')->toArray();;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass an array of conditions like this:

```
$showed = DB::table('tableNameHere')->where([
    ['updated_at', '>=', $month_start],
    ['updated_at', '<=', $month_end],
    ['event', '=', 'showed'],
])->groupBy('id')->get();
```

To count the entries you can then try it this way:

```
$results = $showed->count();
```

Couldn't test the code. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: the count on the result gives me the total for all entries. What I would like ideally is that each "sorted group" (each 'id' group) is counted and that the latest updated_at value for each of those groups is returned together with this count value.